# Write a private property which is list of own class objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class that has some private properties which are list of its own types. When i want to configure the entity framework to consider them when writing to db, i get this error:

> The type 'ICollection< ModelItem>' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

The class is:

```
public partial class ModelItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Lable { get; set; }

    private ICollection<ModelItem> Prop_InputNodes
    {
        get;  set;
    }

    public class ModelItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ModelItem>
    {
        public ModelItemConfiguration()
        {
            Property(x => x.Prop_InputNodes); // <<-- Error raises here
        }
    }
}
```

I almost see all the similar posts in the stackoverflow, but i can't find a solution for it.
Do you know where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: As per the error, `Property` is a method that expects to be called with a non-nullable value type (e.g. `int` or `double`). You are not passing in a non-nullable value type.

Comment: Then how can i save the Prop_InputNodes in the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a collection mapping method:

```
public class ModelItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ModelItem>
{
    public ModelItemConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(x => x.Prop_InputNodes);
    }
}
```

This will create a foreign key field named according to default conventions: `ModelItem_Id`. If you want to change that name you could do something like:

```
this.HasMany(x => x.Prop_InputNodes)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentID"));
```

Comment: The class also have a `Prop_OutputNodes` so I add it to configuration like `HasMany(x => x.Prop_InputNodes).WithMany(y => y.Prop_OutputNodes);`. Hope it can help someone in future.